# Faster ORDER BY LIMIT OFFSET

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a simple request like:

```
SELECT id, champs1, champs2, champs3, count(*) OVER() AS full_count
FROM my_table
ORDER BY champs1 ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

LIMIT and OFFSET are used to paginate my results.

But the request is very slow: ~20 secondes. My "my_table" table has ~8 millions lines.

I put an index on the "champs1" column, but it still very slow.

How can I make this request faster ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long does the query take to run without the `full_count`?  That may be part of the issue (I am not sure).

You might try this:

```
SELECT id, champs1, champs2, champs3, fc.full_count
FROM my_table CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as full_count FROM my_table) fc
ORDER BY champs1 ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Then, be sure you have an index on `my_table(champs1)`.